# How to stop Magento 2 Escaping HTML in Contact form

Tags: forms, contact-us, contact-form, format

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out how to prevent Magento 2 from escaping special chars in the contact form!

At the moment, when a message is sent via the standard contact form in Magento 2, any special characters are escaped to & etc.

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Message Content') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('comment')) ?></textarea>
```

I'm feeling that it has to do with this line of code. I've tried removing the escapeHtml bit, but that just breaks the page..